# Is there a Mail plugin to let me view unread emails first?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, plugins

Similar to Gmail priority inbox, is there a Mail 6.3 (OSX Mountain Lion) plugin that lets me view unread messages first or sort them so they're at top of inbox?

Comment: Sorting by "unread" is built in already

Comment: Used Tiger and Snow Leopard for a long time. Need to learn the new Mail in Mountain Lion better.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can I mark your comment as best answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Mac's mail app you have got the option to create a 'smart mailbox'. This allows you for example to only view unread emails. It can even do that over multiple mailboxes.

Sample rule for unread messages of today (taken from [makeusof.com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/five-essential-smart-mailboxes-for-apple-mail-mac/)):

[image]

If you just want to have the unread messages always on top, there's a sort option for that in the menu between Edit and Mailbox (probably called View).

Comment: To make this an even better answer: can you add a (link to a) screenshot showing how such a mailbox could be defined?

Comment: I would, but my OSX is in Dutch (and therefore Mail too), so I think it will not be very helpful. However, here is a website to a tutorial that does pretty much the same: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/five-essential-smart-mailboxes-for-apple-mail-mac/

Comment: I would take out the Date Received is Today, since that may filter messages you received yesterday that are unread. Also You can add "Message is in Mailbox: Inbox" to filter any other folders you may not be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vincent's answer, you can be more creative with your Smart Mailboxes, but since you're in Mountain Lion, you can sort any Smart Mailbox by Unread/Read status.

[image: Sort Mailbox]